# Is there a way to prevent insert or erase on STL unordered_map?

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I frequently use unordered_maps with fixed / constant keys, but mutable values.  Example: If you have an `enum Dimension{ X, Y }`, you might want to store a data point for each but never allow inserts or deletes for the map.  Updates are OK.

Example initialisation:

```
typedef std::unordered_map<Dimension, std::size_t> Dimension_To_Size_Map;
// assume std::hash has template specialisation for enum
Dimension_To_Size_Map dimension_To_Size_Map =
    { { Dimension.X, 0 }, { Dimension.Y, 0 } };
dimension_To_Size_Map[Dimension.X] = 12;  // update is ok
dimension_To_Size_Map[Dimension.Y] = 17;  // update is ok
dimension_To_Size_Map[(Dimension)7] = 22;  // insert not allowed
dimension_To_Size_Map.erase(Dimension.X);  // erase not allowed
```

It is possible to prevent insert or erase, but allow update, on STL `unordered_map`?

One idea: Copy, rename, and modify an existing implementation of `unordered_map` to remove `insert` and `erase`.

Comment: Wrap the map in your own wrapper class and and only provide the functions you want.

Comment: @NathanOliver given the number of methods exposed by `std::map` that's a lot of boilerplate for such a simple request. Of course if it was a template class it would only have to be done once, I wonder if Boost has something like this?

Comment: P.S. Sometimes the best solution for a problem like this is to just document your invariants, and hope that the people you work with are competent (including yourself when you come back to it a year later).

Comment: @mark-ransom A wrapper is overkill but Boost isn't?

Comment: const Dimension_To_Size_Map dimension_To_Size_Map = ...

Comment: @DieterLücking Updates won't work with const Dimension_To_Size_Map.

Comment: @Qartar it's the difference between code you need to write yourself, and code that's already written and tested.

Comment: `map` is a very inefficient container.  If you don't require new elements, a vector of pairs that you populate, then sort, then use is going to be ridiculously faster.

Comment: @Yakk Here, the map is only inefficient in terms of allocations (memory)

Comment: @Yakk: Point taken.  Wherever possible, I use `unordered_map` instead of `map`.  Question has been updated to remove references to `map`.

Comment: @kevinarpe The problem is not hash vs binary search tree. The problem is that both are node-based.

Comment: @Qartar: Sorry I don't follow your comment.  Who mentioned Boost?  (Or is this a reference to general complaint on SO about avoiding Boost... "too big", etc.)

Comment: @T.C.: Is the node likely to be a pointer to a heap allocated structure (<-- terminology may be imperfect)?  If so, then yes, I can understand.  You will get poor memory locality with such a structure.

Comment: @kevinarpe Yes, locality is the main issue.

Comment: @kevinarpe Mark Ransom, two comments above mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a sorted `std::vector` of `pair<const K, V>`s.  Write manual `[]` and `find` and `begin` and the few methods you care about.

`map` is slow, and one of the reasons it is slow is that it allows new elements.  If you don't allow new elements, write a ridiculously faster container.

Comment: `map is slow`: Can you clarify?  Slow for both read and write?  Or only slow for write?  Also: `write a ridiculously faster container` is a little unclear.  Are you saying: `map` is fast if you don't allow write.  Or saying: If you **need** fast, write your own?

Comment: @kevinarpe I'm saying that `map` is exceedingly general.  It is a node-based structure. Unless you need the full power of `map` (or `unordered_map`), which is rare, the performance hit you get from using it is significant (memory access is 100x slower than an instruction and in a node-based structure you nearly randomly hop over memory). `map` hops more than `unordered_map`, but both dereference pointers to nodes more than once per access (and not arithmetic, which is cache-friendly). Given that everyone should have a contiguous map in their back pocket, write one, and customize the interface.

Comment: @kevinarpe `map` is designed to support `o(logn)` insertion. If you do not insert new elements dinamically (or you do very rarely compared to how many times you search for a key), a sorted vector is more efficient.

Answer (score 4):

You could derive your own map class from std::map via private inheritance and expose only the functions of std::map that you want to provide access to.

Comment: Why private inheritance over a private member?

Comment: @nwp: With private inheritance you can do `using Base::function;` in the `public` section to expose whatever functions you want. Easier to read and write if there are a lot of them.

Comment: Sorry, dumb C++ question.  I am a little weak in this area: Is inheritance of class without virtual destructor OK if you don't call have/use/call any virtual methods?

Comment: Virtual destructors are only needed if you delete objects via the base class. Ex. `Base *object = new Derived(); delete object;` - here Base would have to have a virtual destructor.

Comment: @TamásSzabó: There is no way to cast `Derived *` to `Base *` when you have inherited privately, so accidental deletion via the base pointer is not a concern (and thus the destructor need not be virtual). This is one reason for using private inheritance...

Comment: @Nemo: You are right, indeed. I was just trying to explain the purpose of a virtual destructor.